# Can I run parallel actions from a plain Groovy method in my Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

My Jenkins pipeline is specified in a declarative way. However, in the place I'd like to introduce a parallel step in, I'm forced down into plain Groovy methods:

```
def call(Map parameters) {
    runFirstStep(parameters)
    // add second step that runs in parallel to runFirstStep
}
```

Unexperienced as I am with Groovy and Jenkins, I hoped to make something simple like this work:

```
def call(Map parameters) {
    parallel(
        'First step': {
            runFirstStep(parameters)
        },
        'Second step': {
            runSecondStep(parameters)
        }
    )
}
```

However, this seems to mix up declarative and imperative code in an unsuited way and leads to cryptic NullPointerExceptions.

Is there another, feasible solution for this? Or is overriding the declarative part that surrounds this the only option to squeeze in another parallel step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def call(Map parameters) {

    def steps = [:]

    steps['First step'] = {
        node('master') {
            runFirstStep(parameters)
        }
    }

    steps['Second step'] = {
        node('master') {
            runSecondStep(parameters)
        }
    }

    parallel steps.plus([failFast: true])

}
```